Rational solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2+3(x+y+z)+5=0$
I was solving the above problem in an old math competition.
What I did:
we write the equation as
$$ \Sigma_{cyc}(x+3/2)^2=7/4$$
SO it is equivalent to find rational solutions of
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=7/4$$
Which is in turn equivalent to
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)=7d^2$$ For $(a,b,c,d) \in Z^{4}$.Letting $d=2d_1$, we get
$(a^2+b^2+c^2)=7d_1^2$.
But then $mod(8)$ both sides reveals that all of $a,b,c,d$ must be even.
And now we can see easily by infinite descent that this is not possible.
Hence there are no rational solutions.
I will be really grateful if someone checks my proof . Alternate solutions are also welcome.

Instead of $\sum (x+3/2)^2$ I would write $(x+3/2)^2+(y+3/2)^2+(z+3/2)^2$. For solving $a^2+b^2+c^2=7d^2$ in integers one could also use Gauß $3$-square theorem, if this is available. Are you unsure about the last step by infinite descent?

FYI Per the solution-verification tag: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
